# Ordering testcase execution - Pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I went through some answers for the same issue on Stack Overflow. Most of the answers suggest to use markers. I want to see whether any other alternative is available. Here is my requirement.

test_file1.py:

```
test_class 1
   test_case1
   test_case2
   test_case3...so on
```

test_file2.py:

```
test_class 1
   test_case1
   test_casPls help to solve this.e2
   test_case3...so on
```

Like this I have around 30-40 different .py files with different tests that are specific for testing different functionalities. Now I would like to know how to order the test execution. Is there any way that I can trigger the execution from a single file where I have defined my order of execution?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want ordered tests? In particular, do you want one test to run before all of them?

Comment: I have some dependency with some test scenarios. For ex. I have a file say test_users.py, where i created a user for my application. And also a test case to delete the user after some tests completed.

Now my execution flow should be:

create_user
Execute some other test cases in some other files
now execute delete user test case

Answer (score 0):

You've reached the point where you need to leverage the unit testing framework to do what you want for you, without you having to write the code to do setting up and tearing down.

I will assume you're using Python's `unittest` module, otherwise if you're not then it almost *certainly* has what I'm about to show you (and if it doesn't, it's probably not worth using and you should switch to something better).

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code), you can add a method called `setUp()`, whereby:

> ... the testing framework will automatically call for every single test we run.

```
import unittest

class YourTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Call code here to be set up
        # Save the things into fields with self.whatever = calculate(...)

    def someTest(self):
        # Make use of self.whatever that your automatically run setUp() 
        # has provided for you, since the unit testing framework has
        # called it before this test is run
```

Then there's also `tearDown()` if you need it, which runs code after every unit test.

This means when you implement `setUp` (and optionally `tearDown`), it would run like:

```
test_class1.setUp()
test_class1.test_case1
test_class1.tearDown()

test_class1.setUp()
test_class1.test_case2
test_class1.tearDown()

test_class1.setUp()
test_class1.test_case3
test_class1.tearDown()

...
```

There's a lot more you can do as well, for that I recommend checking out the docs. However this should do what you want it to based on the comment you provided me.

Now if you have code that is shared among them (like maybe some small parameters change), you should investigate the **Distinguishing test iterations using subtests** section at the link provided to see how to use `subTest()` to handle this for you. This supposedly requires Python 3.4+ (which I hope you are using and not something archaic like 2.7).

Finally, if you want to just run something once before all the tests, you can use `setUpClass()` which will do the same thing as `setUp()` except it's run once. See the docs for more details.

In short:

- Use `setUp()` if you need to do something before every test
- Use `setUpClass()` if you need to do something once before all the tests
- Look into `subTest()` if you have a lot of tests that are similar and only the data you feed into the tests change, but this is only to make your code cleaner

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.
I am currently using pytest for my test execution. If i am going to use the unittest i may have to change my total framework. Any i will explore this

Comment: @SivaKumarMamillapalli Was my answer not acceptable for you?